# CSS - Animate css settings back and forth

Tags: css, css-animations

If you hover over the box in my example, then the color of the small box changes slowly from red to yellow. But if you stop hovering then it immediately jumps back to red.

```css
.container { position: relative; background: black; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
.subcontainer { position: absolute; bottom: 10px; width: 100%; height: 20px; background: red; animation-duration: 2s; }

.container:hover .subcontainer { background: yellow; animation-duration: 2s; animation-name: example; }

@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent this instant color change? I tried to add `animation-duration: 2s;` to `.subcontainer` as well, but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `transition` defined in the `.subcontainer` instead of an `animation`

```css
.container { 
    position: relative; 
    background: black; 
    width: 200px; height: 200px; }

.subcontainer { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 10px; width: 100%; height: 20px; 
    background: red; 
    transition: background 2s 0s }

.container:hover .subcontainer { background: yellow;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you add the `background` to `transition` though? I noticed it does also work if you remove it.

Comment: if you remove the property then the transition will occur on every property you change on hover